# Wald's test. Hypothesis testing. Verification.

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, hypothesis-testing, exponential-distribution

> Let $X_1, . . . , X_n ∼ Exp(λ)$, for some unknown parameter $λ > 0$ and let $λ_0$ be a (known) fixed positive number.
>
> 1. Consider the following hypotheses:
>      $H_0 : ”λ = λ_0” vs. H_1 : ”λ ≠ λ_0”$.
>      Give a test with asymptotic level α, for any α ∈ (0, 1).
> 2. Consider the following hypotheses: $H_0 : ”λ ≤ λ_0” vs. H_1 : ”λ > λ_0”.$
>      Give a test with asymptotic level (at most) $α$, for any $α ∈ (0, 1)$

I wanted to proceed with Wald's test. Is it a good choice or I should do this with likelihood ratio test?

$$λ^{MLE}=\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}\\
I(λ_0)=-E\left[\left(n\ln λ-λ\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)''\right]
      =-E\left[-\frac{n}{λ_0^2}\right]
      =\frac{n}{λ_0^2};$$ so

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n} \left(\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}-λ_0\right)
  \to \mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{λ_0^2}{n}\right),$$ in distribution, so

$$T_n=\left[\sqrt{n} \left(\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}-λ_0\right)I(λ_0)\right]^2
     =n\left(\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}-λ_0\right)^2\frac{n^2}{λ_0^4}$$

and in a) we must compute $P(T_n > q_{α/2})$ for $q_{α/2}$ from chi-squared with $n$ degrees of freedom, while in b) $P(T_n > q_{α})$, because in this case its one-sided test.

Is it right?

Comment: Do you mean for the alternative in (1) to have $\ne?$

Comment: @BruceET yes, I am sorry. I will edit it!

Comment: Terminology 'Wald's Test' has many meanings because Wald was prolific. Do you mean to test using normal aprx? If so, I'd say the LR test is better. Seem to recall there's already a Q&A on LR for exponential data on this site.